# Is there a way to access a .net entity property without having to call it directly by using a loop for arrays?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-relationship

In the Entities folder, we have different types of entities like User.cs. In User.cs we have properties for this entity like:

```
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string ProfileImagePath { get; set; }
```

Is there any of way of accessing these properties other than calling it out directly like User.UserName?

It would be great if we could cycle through the list of properties without having to know the property name. We are thinking maybe something like User[0] for the first property in the Entity. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use reflection:

```
foreach(var property in entity.GetType().GetProperties()){
    var value = property.GetValue(entity, null);
    // do whatever you want to do with the value
}
```

It's possible you have to add some `BindingFlags` like `BindingFlag.Instance` and `BindingFlags.Public` (I'm not pretty sure of the defaults). If that's the case, use `entity.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlag.Instance || BindingFlags.Public)`

Comment: It is worth noting that reflection is rather slow. It works well when you use it to collect meta data about given type and build expressions to read the actual data.

Comment: It's slow, but nobody said it has to be fast. It's slow if you have to do a lot of operations but the framework itself uses a lot of reflection, so... It depends on why he needs it.

Comment: And creating the expressions will cost more than using reflection, so it'll depend on if he needs to use it several times or not. In that case, http://fasterflect.codeplex.com/ does the trick

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I have heard that using reflection is slow. If I use this for every entity and property this probably wouldn't be good. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: I'm trying to use this to speed up development quickly. I have decided against using EF because it's slow. I plan on using this just to pass in values from the stored procedure to the entity.

Comment: @Hoang This isn't a simple bit of code. You can find a sample on how to read object properties/fields here https://plus.google.com/u/0/110584455223195182055/posts/2o9MH5DceJF Setting them would be similar

Comment: If you will be using a stored procedure, then you can just use a `DataTable` and access all the values directly using `DataRow.ItemArray`

Comment: Anyway... I don't know what are you implementing, but besides it's true EF is slower than calling directly the DB, it's ok for most of the development made in .NET. I mean... .NET is slower in comparison with C or C++. The same applies for reflection, it needs to be analyzed in a context. The best approach is to do the simpler way and then, if it doesn't perform as expected, start optimizing it.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look at Reflection. Something like this lets you enumerate all string properties values of an object `yourInstance` of class `A`:

```
foreach(var propertyInfo in typeof(A).GetProperties())
{
    if(Type.GetTypeCode(propertyInfo.PropertyType) == TypeCode.String)
        Console.WriteLine((string)propertyInfo.GetValue(yourInstance, null));
}
```

Comment: @ivowiblo: He may probably just enumerate properties of some specific type. If not, the op can just leave out this check...